# How file permissions are stored in inode?

Tags: permissions, files, development, ftp, command-line

Suppose there's two pc - "A" and "B". Then if A downloads a files from B , then what would be the file permission of that downloaded file? Is it possible that the downloaded file in A will have an Inode entry with all it's permissions from B & store B's user account as the owner ? If that's the case then is it impossible to change that files permission on A if "others" [as in user-group-others] doesn't have the right to write on that file?

e.g. if this is the case ,
__x __x __x  file.txt  [On B]

then what would be the file permission on A of that same file downloaded from B [e.g. through vsftpd]?

1. __x __x __x    file.txt [On A]

or

1. rw_x rw_x rw_x     file.txt [On A] [i.e. defined by A's default umask value]

Comment: Downloading means read, transport and write.. so the downloaded file will be with permission for the user who is logged in B because you are writing there. Maybe some expert can explain well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The downloaded file will have the permissions depending on the system A settings (umask). Basically at the moment the file is copied the file belongs to the user on A. 
To be more accurate, the data from the file is transferred to the ftp client on system A. Only the data, not the metadata (in the Inode) that holds access rights, ownership, create/access/modify date .... and other stuff.
I could download the file via ftp and store it on a non unix file system (FAT) for example, that has none or a completely different security mechanism.

So basically in your case the ftp protocol is the problem.

If you want to transfer the ownership info as well you could use `tar`for example to archive the file including (almost) all metadata. Then transfer the archive to A and extract it with the appropriate options to keep the original ownerships.